# MVC form with collection not included in JSON serialization

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a working MVC Razor page with a collection of textboxes that look like the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateOrEdit", "Vehicle", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "vehicle-details-form"}))
{
    //stuff
    <input id="Damages_0__IssueDescription" name="Damages[0].IssueDescription" type="text">
    //stuff
}
```

When I post the page as a regular page submit, these bind successfully to the model on the following property:

```
public List<VehicleDamageViewModel> Damages { get; set; }
```

However, I'm now trying to submit the form via Ajax and JSON in the following manner:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("CreateOrEditFromCollect", "Vehicle")', $('#vehicle-details-form').serialize(), function(result) {
    // success
}).fail(function(a, b, error) {
    // fail
});
```

I can see the textbox values are not being included in the serialized JSON.  How can I include them?

Comment: What is this `name="Damages[0].IssueDescription"` meant to be

Comment: Do you mean the formatting of the name, or the purpose of the textbox?  It captures a description from the user.  The naming format is the standard pattern for binding a list of sub-models to a master view model in MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the input controls were actually falling outside of the `form`, because there was a nested `form` causing an early closure of the `form`.  The code as illustrated in the original question was correct.